# What is a "unique viewer" for video?

Tags: video, streaming, http-live-streaming, metrics, wowza

Our customers keep asking us to add unique viewers count to our media streaming metrics, similar to unique visitors in web metrics. We already provide wide variety of stats for traffic, bandwidth and all sorts of connections-related stats in our reporting panel but this one is still in our wishlist for a long time.

Each time we get back to unique viewers metric we come to a question like "What is the unique properties we can rely on to identify a viewer?"

Obviously, we could use IP. But it's not much unique these days anymore. Large groups of people may have internet access from single proxy with common IP address. Also, internet providers may send visitor's traffic through different interfaces depending on traffic type (like splitting text and video). We see that often for Asia-Pacific and Latin America ISPs.

We could use some properties for HTTP-based protocols like HLS. This might be ETag header or a combination of User-Agent and IP address.  But we also need to handle binery protocols like RTMP and RTSP where this is not quite possible.

We can assume some property to be unique within 24 hours because this is the largest data bucket in our reporting system. E.g. if we rely on IP and some guy has same IP during 2 days - we'll show him as a unique visitor for both days.

So my question is - what are best ways to calculate the uniqueness of a given media streaming client within a given period of time?

Any feedback is highly appreciated. Thank you.